# Does the Avogadro have to be killed with an EMP for the Tower of Babble

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

So I've been through watching the videos on YouTube to find out how to do this ball-buster of an achievement. Me and a friend thought we'd try out doing it two player seeing as it's been proven that it's possible.

We finally got the Avogadro under the pylon and killed him with the **galvaknuckles** in the hope that he would travel up the pylon and we could continue. But he didn't go up!

Does he *have* to be killed with the EMPs? Are we really expected to repeatedly try again until we get the EMPs out of the box? Seriously?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is confirmed. I have first killed the Avogadro with just galvaknuckles but he did not travel up the tower and I could not continue the easter egg. It must be an EMP grenade that he is killed with. Thanks to KillerRabbit but I did it with just two players myself so 2-4 players are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Avogadro has to be killed with the EMPs while its under the tower, there is no other way.

p.s. I am pretty sure that it has to be done with 4 players.